# Problem WordPress StackExchange Email Notifications

Tags: discussion, email

I seem to receive email notifications from this forum a day or more late. Is this a problem with the StackExchange system, or is there a setting in my profile somewhere that sets a delay for email notifications?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not receiving answer email notifications](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/198/not-receiving-answer-email-notifications)

Answer (score 3):

I vaguely remember reading this is intentional for some reason. Stack Exchange sites are not really same as generic forums, they do a lot of things at their own pace and with own reasoning.

Also question related to site itself should be asked on [Meta](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

[This is intentional and will not be changed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14555/notify-more-frequently-than-once-a-day/14600#14600)

Comment: Good link, thanks for pointing to it.

Answer (score 0):

yes it would be nice and helpful also if the email notifications can send to users immediately after an answer/comment made in a question,
also a nice feature option is to select or not if you want to receive email notifications about new questions.

thanks a lot,
Philip