# Shouldn't notifications methods have some prominence in the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Having the [SENotifier](https://stackapps.com/q/3081/10590) installed, sometimes I reply in almost real time to comments made in Q&A.
And feel it's a pity the other party haven't got an instant notification, so the problem gets solved while we have our hands at it.

My research here in the Meta shows this two main threads about the issue, and they involve email notifications:

- [Problem WordPress StackExchange Email Notifications](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292)
- [No email notices on comments etc.](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/456)

In the first, @tnorthcutt points to this StackOverflow Meta question:

- [Notify more frequently than once a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14555/185667)

And there, @JeffAtwood makes a comment about the use of the [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/) for this kind of instant notification.

Which brings me to my point: shouldn't **all those** Notification Apps and Extensions be promoted so new users (and maybe not so new) can get a better interaction with the whole Stack?

I really think that, at least, a new item in the FAQ would be welcomed: *How do (can?) I receive notifications for Q, A and C(omments)?*.

Comment: I'm all for this, maybe even a giant banner :) because the drive by questions really degrade this stack.

Comment: Moved this Q to the [Mothership Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164439/185667).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do it would be to roll out a special notification for the first question asked and first answer received for each user, and maybe again if it's been some time (30 days?) from their last login.

This would give a heads-up for the newbies:

> "thanks for your first question. If you want to be alerted when
>   someone answers, take a look at the StackApps availabe"

And also would alert those that come once in a while:

> "hey, did you know you can make better use of this?"

+1 for the FAQ item suggestion, easy to fix and straight to the point.

Comment: Yep, the auto-notification email is a close-voted feature here and in other Metas, but having all those Apps at hand and not promoting their use doesn't seems quite right...